# Fixing an line in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

**the line i got the error :**

```
IEnumerator enumerator = this.ListBox1.Items.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    object objectValue = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(enumerator.Current);
    list2.Add(Conversions.ToString(objectValue));
}
```

the error is in the first line.

**error i got :**

> Error  1   'System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.GetEnumerator()' is inaccessible due to its protection level

how can i fix it ?

thx for the helpers !

MahApps wpf app

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: why not just do foreach(object o in listbox1.items) { list2.add(convertsion.tostring(o);} (casing of items not included)

Comment: For further questions on Stackoverflow, please read the How to ask a good question part of the FAQ. Your title doesn't relate to the problem at all. No way to know what the question is about before reading it.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest fix would be to use the language support for iterators:

```
foreach (object value in ListBox1.Items)
{
    list2.Add(Conversions.ToString(value));
}
```

If you expect the values to already be strings, you could make the `foreach` loop cast for you implicitly:

```
foreach (string value in ListBox1.Items)
{
    list2.Add(value);
}
```

Or if you're creating a new list anyway, you could use a one-liner:

```
var list2 = ListBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

The reason your current code doesn't work is that [`CollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) uses *explicit interface implementation* for `IEnumerable`. You *could* change your code to just:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = ((IEnumerable)this.ListBox1.Items).GetEnumerator();
```

... but it would be *much* better to use one of the approaches above.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
foreach (var item in this.ListBox1.Items)
{
    list2.Add(Conversions.ToString(item));
}
```